# Get Rows which are updated in new table compared to old table -SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

I have a table as

```
id  Description Tag
1       ABC         Tag1
2       DEF         Tag2
3       ABC         Tag1
4       ABC         Tag1
5       GHI         Tag3
6       DEF         Tag2
```

and whenever i need to make multiple changes I will create a new table and change the values (tag column). I need a query to get the rows where the tag column has a different value compared to old table.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: You may write trigger to achieve this functionality,On After Update event on that specific old table.

Comment: what you need excatly...create new table or use mysql trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this

```
select a.id, a.description, a.tag, b.tag
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.tag<>b.tag
and a.id=b.id
```